# writing functions in haskell that work on associated types only

Tags: haskell, typeclass, associated-types

I'm trying to find a more elegant way to write the following code.

```
class C c where
    type E c :: * -> *

class C c => A c where
    g :: E c a -> E c a

class (C c, A c) => D c where
    f :: E c a -> E c a

instance A c => D c where
    f = g
```

This produces an error.

```
Test.hs:58:9:
    Could not deduce (E c0 ~ E c)
    from the context (A c)
      bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:57:10-19
    NB: `E' is a type function, and may not be injective
    Expected type: E c a
      Actual type: E c0 a
    Expected type: E c a -> E c a
      Actual type: E c0 a -> E c0 a
    In the expression: g
    In an equation for `f': f = g
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

My current solution is to add a dummy variable, from which it can derive
which particular C is in use.

```
class C c where
    type E c :: * -> *

class C c => A c where
    g_inner :: c -> E c a -> E c a
g = g_inner undefined

class (C c, A c) => D c where
    f_inner :: c -> E c a -> E c a
f = f_inner undefined

instance A c => D c where
    f_inner = g_inner
```

I know this is another instance of associated types not being injective,
but I can't quite figure it out. Sure, E might not be injective, but it
seems somewhere the information that *g* will work on the particular
(E c) referenced in class *D* has been lost.

Any explanation, and more importantly better workarounds would be
much appreciated. Thanks!

### edit

Okay, I see switching `type` to `data` makes the code work.

I'm trying to sound out how this might work. Each `c` creates a new data type `E c`. In the instance context, we have to match `forall a. ((E) c) a -> ((E) c) a` with `forall a. ((E) c) a -> ((E) c) a`. Denoting `F = E c`, we are then matching `forall a. F a -> F a` with itself.

I'm having trouble seeing where things break with the type synonyms (associated types) case. Sure, one could define two instances of `A` which both have signature `(E c) a -> (E c) a`. But, why would it be wrong to use the definition from the instance `A c` which is in scope?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would an associated _data_ family work for you here (instead of an associated type family)? Each instance would need to declare a brand new data type, but `E` would be injective then, and it would be possible to infer `c` from `E c`.

Comment: Actually you can't event wrote `instance C c => A c where g = g`. Because type of right side of `=` is going to be deduced from function `g`. That's why it says `c0` (i.e. there is no way to prove that it is `c`)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that, from just `E c a -> E c a`, the compiler doesn't know which instance `C` to choose.

Associated type families are just type synonyms.  So the class

```
class C c => A c where
    g :: E c a -> E c a
```

from the typechecker's perspective may as well be

```
class C c => A c where
    g :: m a -> m a
```

As the class variable `c` isn't mentioned, there's no way to determine which instance dictionary should be used to select the function.  Although this is because type families aren't injective, I agree that it isn't obvious from the error message that this is the problem.

Using a data family as Daniel Wagner suggests may be the most elegant solution.  I've sometimes been able to invert my type families, so that instead of getting an `E c` for a particular `c`, I instead choose `c` based on `E c`.  In this case, that would give:

```
class E (e :: * -> *) where
    type C e :: *

class E e => A e where
    g :: e a -> e a

class (A e) => D e where
    f :: e a -> e a

instance A e => D e where
    f = g
```

Depending on what else you're doing, this may work for you.

This problem aside, having a separate instance doesn't make much sense.  Since `A` is available as a super class constraint, you can just set `f = g` as a default method.  Doing so will be much less trouble; you probably don't actually want an `instance D e where ...`.

Comment: Is there any example of using 'inverted type family'. It will be helpful to look at one.